# Entrust - Get Permission Based on Role

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, roles, user-permissions

I am using Entrust in Laravel 5.1. From their api, I can see that I can check the user permissions like this: 
`$user->can('edit_posts'),`
But, I want to be able to check a permission for a specific role like this:
`$role->can('edit_posts'),`
that returns *True* or *False*

The above doesnt work. Is that not possible? What is the right method to check if a role say `manager` has the right to `edit_post`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have done now although I am not sure if its the correct conventional method to follow, but it works.

What I did was created a static function inside the `Role()` Model that checks the `role_id` with `permission` and returns true or false. Here is the code:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;
use DB;

class Role extends EntrustRole {   

      /**
        * Checks if the role has a permission by its name.
        *
        * @param numeric $roleId|string $permissionName - Role ID and permission name.
        *
        * @return bool
      */
         public static function hasPermission($roleId, $permissionName)
         {
              $role = Role::findOrFail($roleId);
              $role_permissions = $role->perms()->get();
                   foreach ($role_permissions as $permission) {
                       if ($permission->name == $permissionName) {
                           return true;
                       }
                   }
              return false;
         }
}
```

Usage in Controller:

```
$hasPermission = Role::hasPermission($roleId, 'edit_post');
```